# Cronbach's alpha, When to use it

Tags: descriptive-statistics, regression-coefficients, cronbachs-alpha

I am a bit confused about the use of Cronbach Alpha. I have a questionnaire I administered to 20 respondents. I have gotten the data back from the survey. I am told I need to do an Internal consistency analysis of the questionnaire which is basically a test of its reliability. This is where I get confused.

1) Am I using Cronbach Alpha to test for internal consistency of the questions in the questionnaire before the survey or am I testing the data I got from the survey in the completed questionnaire for internal consistency using Cronbach Alpha?

2) If I am testing the questions in the questionnaire without any data from respondents how do I do the cronbach alpha test??

3) Do I really need to do a cronbach alpha test or is there another test for internal consistency?

Below is a brief outline of my questionnaire

5. Does your organisation use any type of social media tools?
   A.          Yes
   B.          No
6. Why does your organisation not use social media tools?
   A.          Lack technical personnel
   B.          Lack of funds
   C.          Management unwilling to invest in social media tools
   D.          No obvious benefits for using social media tools
   E.          Social media not applicable to our type of business
   H.          Other (please specify)………………………………….
7. What social media tools does your organisation use?
   (Tick all that apply)
   A.          Microblogging (i.e. Twitter)
   B.          Social Networking (i.e. Bebo, Facebook, LinkedIn)
   C.          Photo Sharing (i.e. Flickr, Instagram)
   D.          Video Sharing (i.e. YouTube)
   E.          Live casting (i.e. Ustream.tv, Skype)
8. Does your organisation have a website?
   A.          Yes
   B.          No
9. Has your organisation’s use of social media networks increased traffic to your           website?
   A.          Yes
   B.          No